# flutter https and http check

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i have 2 base url's

String HttpsBaseUrl="https://www.example.com/Api/"  //Certificate valid

String HttpBaseUrl="http://www.example.com/Api/"    //Certificate expired

```
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
  "firstName": firstName,
  "lastName": lastName,
  "email": email,
  "contactNo": mobile,
});

Dio dio = Dio();
var response = await dio.post(Constants.HttpsBaseUrl+ "signup", data: formData); //HTTPS
```

i want to check if my host certificate has expired if it is then i want to use

```
Dio dio = Dio(); 
var response = await dio.post(Constants.HttpBaseUrl+ "signup", data: formData); //HTTP
```

**also if my host certificate has expired how can i redirect to my backup server with different URL?**

Comment: you could simply go with the HTTPS version better.

Comment: that's not what I am looking for actually, Let me add more details